# Record live stream video using FMS 3.5

Tags: flash-media-server

I am recording live stream on a server side (using FMS 3.5.3).
while recording video recording stops.
I checked recorded video length, it is always different,sometimes only 2 minites, sometimes 10 minutes, sometimes 20 minutes

Anyone faced this problem?
Will be glad if you can help me to solve this!

code:

```
Client.prototype.RecordStart = function()
{
    trace("RecordStart");
    var ns = Stream.get("mp4:test:f4v"); 
    if (ns)
    { 
        ns.record(); 
        ns.play("livestream",-1,-1,false); 
    } 
}

Client.prototype.RecordStop = function()
{
    trace("RecordStop");
    var ns = Stream.get("mp4:test.f4v");
    ns.record(false);
    ns.play(false);
    ns.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here

```
var ns = Stream.get("mp4:test:f4v");
```

it should be as `"mp4:test:f4v"` instead of `"mp4:test.f4v"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still stuck with the problem, the solution offered by ctdavids‌ here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/865510 worked for me!

The problem is that

var ns = Stream.get("mp4:test:f4v");

assigns the recording stream to the ns variable that has the scope inside the function. Thus, within a few minutes, the variable would get garbage collected. This would make the recording to abruptly stop with no status notifications or error messages.

To fix the issue, just put the variable inside of a global object, say,

var ns = Stream.get("mp4:test:f4v"); 
strMaps[recordingStreamName] = ns;

where strMaps is the global variable (Object), recordingStreamName is just a unique name for the recording.

When you stop the recording, you can delete this global reference using

delete strMaps[recordingStreamName];

Hope this helps!